# LLDB python debugger register read

Tags: python, ios, debugging, trace, lldb

I need to trace program execution, so I decided to make infinite loop, and read pc register and make step.

Platform: **IOS**

In such way I want to trace program's execution  flow.

**Question is - how should i get $pc register  through LLDB python API?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program will likely have more than one thread, and each thread will have a different PC.  So you would start with your SBProcess object, then it has a "threads" property for iterating over threads - represented by the SBThread object.  The SBThread has a "frames" property which is an array of all the "SBFrames", and frames[0] is the bottom-most frame.  The SBFrame has "pc" property which is the pc.  This table of the Python SB API's might help you out:

[LLDB Python APIs](http://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/index.html)

However, what you are trying to do won't work under Xcode - which is generally the only way to do debugging on iOS.  Xcode and Python currently fight over who gets to control process execution, and at some point the wrong actor wins and execution stalls.

You can do this sort of thing using a stand-alone Python driver, an example of which is:

[Process Events Example](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/python/process_events.py)

But since you can't really attach to an iOS process from stand-alone lldb, this is hard to use for iOS development.

BTW, I've occasionally done what you are describing on Mac OS X, and it is also really really slow.  You would only want to do this when you are desperate.

You can sometimes get the same effect by putting breakpoints on every function entry point, which you can do on the lldb command line using:

```
(lldb) break set -r .
```

and if you only care about tracing through some given modules, you can add the --shlib option one or more times to the "break set" line to restrict the breakpoints to those libraries.  Then write a breakpoint command (which you can do in Python) to gather the requisite information.  This will still be slow, but is closer to useable.

Comment: thank you so much, Jim! Really useful info. I am not developing, I'm exploring some malware binary, so I want to trace it's activity and then map extracted information to IDA to get deeper. If you have more advices, please share :D Thank you again!